# The "byte-for-byte" terminology, what does it mean?

Tags: terminology

I would like to understand this terminology "byte-for-byte" in this phrase:

> Byte-for-byte, JavaScript is still the most expensive resource we send to mobile phones, because it can delay interactivity in large ways.

This terminolgoy appears in this article [The Cost Of JavaScript In 2018](https://medium.com/@addyosmani/the-cost-of-javascript-in-2018-7d8950fbb5d4)

Comment: sounds like a takeoff on "pound for pound" from Boxing rankings...if you were to make a ranking of content-types [sent to a mobile device] by bytes transferred, JavaScript content would rank highly.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it means a trade-off, an exchange of goods or services, in which one transfer is contingent upon the other. Like: eye for an eye or quid pro quo,.. but in technology manner.

Because Js not really optimized for mobile phones about the sizes.